# PHP regex backreference to uppercase (german chars)

Tags: php, regex, uppercase, backreference

I want to search a text after a **specific regex pattern** (matching one or two words followed by dot and whitespace). Then I use `preg_replace` with a backreference. Is it possible to make the text contained by the **backreference to get *uppercase***?

```
$teaser = "Special markup. This is the remaining text..."
$pattern = '/(^\w+\s\w+\.\s)|(^\w+\.\s)/i'; //match one or two words followed by dot and whitespace
$replacement = '<span style="color: red">'$0'. '</span>'; //$0 is the backreference
$text = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $teaser );
```

My expected output:

```
 SPECIAL MARKUP. This is the remaining text...
```

Have also tried to using, without any success:

```
$replacement = '<span style="color: red">' . strtoupper( '$0' ) . '</span>';
```

Helps appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/preg-replace-callback

Comment: What is the special mark up? Maybe we could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a callback to achieve this as suggested in the comments.

```
$str = "Special markup. This is the remaining text...";

$str = preg_replace_callback('~^\w+(?:\s\w+)?\.\s~', 
     function($m) {
         return '<span style="color: red">'.strtoupper($m[0]).'</span>';
      }, $str);

echo $str;
```

Output

```
<span style="color: red">SPECIAL MARKUP. </span>This is the remaining text...
```

Comment: Just for future reference. In my case I used the *regex* `~^\S+(?:\s\S+)?\.\s~`, because I had to match also **german special chars** such as *öäüß*. Also I had to use the `mb_strtoupper( $m[0], 'UTF-8')`-function. Otherwise the special chars wouldn't change case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its slightly more complicated, but still easy. Use preg_replace_callback:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('regex', function($m) {
    return str_to_upper($m[1]);
}, $caption);
```

so in your case you should be able to put:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback( $pattern , function ($m) {
    return '<span style="color: red">' . strtoupper( $m[1] ) . '</span>';
}, $teaser);
```

That should work.